# Why is TextFormField Not work and Keyboard not showing on iphone simulator in android studio

Tags: dart, textfield, flutter-textformfield

### Heads up!! This works on the google pixel simulator and my personal Android phone

---

So I am creating a form for an authentication screen. I was setting up the UI in android studio, just trying to get a simple form going when I came across this roadblock. For some reason, the iPhone TextFormField is rendered, and it's validator works too, but the form itself produces this error:

```
======== Exception caught by services library ======================================================
The following StackOverflowError was thrown during a platform message callback:
Stack Overflow

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:837:3)
#1      Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#2      _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#3      Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#4      _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#5      Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#6      _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#7      Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#8      _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#9      Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#10     _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#11     Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#12     _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#13     Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#14     _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#15     Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#16     _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#17     Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#18     _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#19     Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#20     _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#21     Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#22     _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#23     Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#24     _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#25     Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#26     _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#27     Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#28     _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#29     Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#30     _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#31     Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#32     _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#33     Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#34     _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#35     Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#36     _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#37     Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#38     _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#39     Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#40     _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#41     Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#42     _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#43     Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
...
...
#4513   Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#4514   _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#4515   Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#4516   _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#4517   Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#4518   _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#4519   Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#4520   _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#4521   Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#4522   _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#4523   Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#4524   DiagnosticsProperty.valueToString (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:2741:60)
#4525   DiagnosticsProperty.toDescription (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:2755:21)
#4526   TextTreeRenderer._debugRender (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:1194:32)
#4527   TextTreeRenderer.render (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:1126:14)
#4528   TextTreeRenderer._debugRender (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:1304:39)
#4529   TextTreeRenderer.render (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:1126:14)
#4530   DiagnosticsNode.toStringDeep.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:1744:9)
#4531   DiagnosticsNode.toStringDeep (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:1751:6)
#4532   DiagnosticsNode.toString.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:1661:18)
#4533   DiagnosticsNode.toString (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:1673:6)
#4534   Diagnosticable.toString.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:3111:78)
#4535   Diagnosticable.toString (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:3113:6)
#4536   _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#4537   HardwareKeyboard._assertEventIsRegular.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/hardware_keyboard.dart:437:60)
#4538   HardwareKeyboard._assertEventIsRegular (package:flutter/src/services/hardware_keyboard.dart:452:6)
#4539   HardwareKeyboard.handleKeyEvent (package:flutter/src/services/hardware_keyboard.dart:543:5)
#4540   KeyEventManager.handleRawKeyMessage (package:flutter/src/services/hardware_keyboard.dart:821:35)
#4541   BasicMessageChannel.setMessageHandler.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:73:49)
#4542   BasicMessageChannel.setMessageHandler.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:72:47)
#4543   _DefaultBinaryMessenger.setMessageHandler.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/binding.dart:379:35)
#4544   _DefaultBinaryMessenger.setMessageHandler.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/binding.dart:376:46)
#4545   _invoke2.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:205:15)
#4548   _invoke2 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:204:10)
#4549   _ChannelCallbackRecord.invoke (dart:ui/channel_buffers.dart:42:5)
#4550   _Channel.push (dart:ui/channel_buffers.dart:132:31)
#4551   ChannelBuffers.push (dart:ui/channel_buffers.dart:329:17)
#4552   PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPlatformMessage (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:544:22)
#4553   _dispatchPlatformMessage (dart:ui/hooks.dart:92:31)
(elided 2 frames from dart:async)
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by services library ======================================================
The following StackOverflowError was thrown during a platform message callback:
Stack Overflow

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:837:3)
#1      Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#2      _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#3      Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#4      _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#5      Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#6      _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#7      Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#8      _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#9      Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#10     _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#11     Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#12     _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#13     Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#14     _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#15     Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#16     _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#17     Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#18     _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#19     Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#20     _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#21     Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#22     _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#23     Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#24     _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#25     Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#26     _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#27     Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#28     _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#29     Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#30     _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#31     Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#32     _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#33     Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#34     _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#35     Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#36     _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#37     Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#38     _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#39     Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#40     _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#41     Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#42     _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#43     Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
...
...
#4513   Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#4514   _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#4515   Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#4516   _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#4517   Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#4518   _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#4519   Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#4520   _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#4521   Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#4522   _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#4523   Duration.toString (dart:core/duration.dart:275:25)
#4524   DiagnosticsProperty.valueToString (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:2741:60)
#4525   DiagnosticsProperty.toDescription (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:2755:21)
#4526   TextTreeRenderer._debugRender (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:1194:32)
#4527   TextTreeRenderer.render (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:1126:14)
#4528   TextTreeRenderer._debugRender (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:1304:39)
#4529   TextTreeRenderer.render (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:1126:14)
#4530   DiagnosticsNode.toStringDeep.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:1744:9)
#4531   DiagnosticsNode.toStringDeep (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:1751:6)
#4532   DiagnosticsNode.toString.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:1661:18)
#4533   DiagnosticsNode.toString (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:1673:6)
#4534   Diagnosticable.toString.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:3111:78)
#4535   Diagnosticable.toString (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:3113:6)
#4536   _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:846:19)
#4537   HardwareKeyboard._assertEventIsRegular.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/hardware_keyboard.dart:437:60)
#4538   HardwareKeyboard._assertEventIsRegular (package:flutter/src/services/hardware_keyboard.dart:452:6)
#4539   HardwareKeyboard.handleKeyEvent (package:flutter/src/services/hardware_keyboard.dart:543:5)
#4540   KeyEventManager.handleRawKeyMessage (package:flutter/src/services/hardware_keyboard.dart:821:35)
#4541   BasicMessageChannel.setMessageHandler.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:73:49)
#4542   BasicMessageChannel.setMessageHandler.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:72:47)
#4543   _DefaultBinaryMessenger.setMessageHandler.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/binding.dart:379:35)
#4544   _DefaultBinaryMessenger.setMessageHandler.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/binding.dart:376:46)
#4545   _invoke2.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:205:15)
#4548   _invoke2 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:204:10)
#4549   _ChannelCallbackRecord.invoke (dart:ui/channel_buffers.dart:42:5)
#4550   _Channel.push (dart:ui/channel_buffers.dart:132:31)
#4551   ChannelBuffers.push (dart:ui/channel_buffers.dart:329:17)
#4552   PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPlatformMessage (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:544:22)
#4553   _dispatchPlatformMessage (dart:ui/hooks.dart:92:31)
(elided 2 frames from dart:async)
====================================================================================================
```

I have literally restarted my project several times but the error persists. Could someone please help me with this problem?

Here is my code:

```
final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text(
          "Login",
        ),
      ),
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextFormField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Enter your email',
              ),
              validator: (String? value) {
                if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please enter some text';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  // Validate will return true if the form is valid, or false if
                  // the form is invalid.
                  if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                    // Process data.
                  }
                },
                child: const Text('Submit'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to fix it by switching to the stable channel of Flutter.

```
flutter channel stable
```

Also, make sure to upgrade to the latest version of Flutter by running this command

```
flutter upgrade
```

Thanks